# Detecting if fonts are embedded in a pdf

Tags: pdf, itext, embedded-fonts

We have a requirement that our PDFs embed our fonts.  After solving the problem of embedding them, I would like to add a check for that to our unit tests. We are in java, we are primarily using `itext`, but we could always use a different library for this test.

Comment: Does http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-list-of-embedded-fonts-in-a-PDF-td3153.html help?